# Calculate the sides of a 2d polygon from the vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

So how would I go about calculating the sides of a 2d polygon? They're non-concave poly's, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps this would be of some help: http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonsides.html

Comment: There is no unique solution. For example, consider the vertices of a triangle and an interior point: there are three polygons that can be formed. Moreoveor, if you allow self-intersecting polygons, then you can choose any ordering of the points and join them up in that order. Do you want to avoid these?

Answer (score 1):

For non-concave polygons, you can just find the convex hull of the points, via any of the normal algorithms (google, for example, "quick-hull" or "graham scan").